# How to check whether the url is up or down using python3

Tags: python-3.x, url, urllib3

I am trying to get all the working domain from the text and check whether the domain is up or not but when I import the domain from the list and using urllib lib I run through it doesn't work

I have tried to create a list in which all domain are added but it is not working

```py
import urllib.request
import sys
import os

web_list = sys.argv[1]

with open(web_list) as f:
    sub = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

for i in sub:
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(sub)
    if url == 200:
        print(url)
    else:
        pass
```

I want output showing the domain which is working.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "http_checker.py", line 11, in <module>
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(sub)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 516, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'```

Comment: shouldn't it be `url = urllib.request.urlopen(i)` instead of `url = urllib.request.urlopen(sub)`?